# BricxCC not seeing USB Tower in Windows 10

Tags: rcx

I have a similar problem to [BricxCC not seeing Serial Tower in Windows 10](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/11576/bricxcc-not-seeing-serial-tower-in-windows-10)  except I have a USB tower (not a serial one). 
I have spent hours on this and didn't manage to solve it. Tried installing it on Windows 10 following this guide: http://www.legoengineering.com/rcx-usb-tower-support/. I am trying to connect to a RCX2.0

Here are my 3 questions :

1. Can USB tower work with Windows 10 64-bit version?
2. How can I make sure my LEGO tower is getting the signal?
3. Why am I still getting the same message "No connection to the programmable brick..." with the version '''bricxcc_setup_33810_20130220.exe''' which apparently solves the issue ?

Please help ! I'm about to give up ..

Comment: See the answer to this question [Lego Mindstorms RCX RIS 2.0 IR tower Windows 10 64-bit driver](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/8190/lego-mindstorms-rcx-ris-2-0-ir-tower-windows-10-64-bit-driver#8198)